# How to host an OSRM instance in AWS Fargate?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, python-requests, osrm

I've been trying to set up an OSRM-backend instance within Fargate. However, I haven't been able to successfully do so. I've read in other places on how to host in EC2 instances, however, none on how to host this on AWS Fargate.

I've been able to modify the base docker image of OSRM-backend below (base image exposes port 5000):

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend

WORKDIR /data

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl

RUN curl http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/ireland-and-northern-ireland-latest.osm.pbf --output ni-latest.osm.pbf && \
    osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua ni-latest.osm.pbf && \
    osrm-partition ni-latest.osrm && \
    osrm-customize ni-latest.osrm

CMD ["osrm-routed", "--algorithm", "mld", "ni-latest.osrm", "--max-matching-size","50000"]
```

Once I've pushed this into the container registry, setting up the task definition within the elastic container service, the status code 200 was given and the following:

```
[info] starting up engines, v5.22.0
[info] Threads: 4
[info] IP address: 0.0.0.0
[info] IP port: 5000
[info] http 1.1 compression handled by zlib version 1.2.11
[info] Listening on: 0.0.0.0:5000
[info] running and waiting for requests
```

Which runs as expected, however, after given the public IP within the ECS task, and trying to call it within sagemaker notebook:

```
response = requests.get('http://{ECSpublicIP}:80/match/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407?overview=full&geometries=geojson')
```

It gives a connection error code 111 and I have not been able to figure out why. Is hosting OSRM on Fargate possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, don't know if this still is relevant but yes it should be possible.
Are you able to reach it through localhost when deployed locally?
Also make sure to have your container port mapping in place, see this link for more information about task networking https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/